# How to ignore a function within for loop after first iteration in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I have a function within for loop. in this function i load a file and interpolation is done for data point as can be seen below. this process is very costly. Can I skip this process after first iteration and use just "F" function (CAR = F(p1, p2)) for (p1, p2) as input values?

```
function CAR = AcAd (p1, p2)
num = xlsread('Book.xlsx');
x = num(:, 1); y = num(:, 2); z = num(:, 3);
t1 = 0.05:0.02:2; t2 = 0.05:0.02:0.5;
F = scatteredInterpolant(x, y, z);
[qx, qy] = meshgrid(t1, t2); 
qz = F(qx, qy);

CAR = F(p1, p2);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to solve this problem:

1. Ask the user to pass in the data: `function CAR = AcAd (p1, p2, num)` and only load it once outside the function.
2. Have a [global](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html) to store the data:

---

```
function CAR = AcAd (p1, p2)
if (~exist('num'))
    num = xlsread('Book.xlsx');
end
```

This is obviously just for `num` but can be easily expanded to get `F` in the same ways.